# Getter/setter in SQLAlchemy ORM mapped Declarative Table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, python-decorators

I want to change a value into a different format during assignment to a mapped table object in SQLAlchemy and then perform the reverse formatting for that column when selecting the row.

### Desired

```py
# Adds a row with a formatted start_time="2023-03-01 12:00:00"
my_table_row = MyTable(start_time="20230301-120000")
session.add(my_table_row)
session.flush()


# Returns a MyTable object with an inverse formatted start_time="20230301-120000"
result = session.execute(
    select(MyTable).filter_by(start_time="2023-03-01 12:00:00")
).scalar_one()
```

### Attempted

I am trying to use the `@property` and `@attr.setter` decorator as per [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators). However, the values are added and retrieved from the DB without any formatting changed.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class MyTable(Base):

    __table__ = "test_table"

    _start_time: Mapped[str] = mapped_column("start_time", String(23), nullable=True, index=True)

    @property
    def start_time(self):
        return convert_from_db_format(self._start_time)

    @start_time.setter
    def start_time(self, start_time):
        self._start_time = convert_to_db_format(start_time)


def convert_to_db_format(input_time):
    return datetime.strptime(
        input_time,
        "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"
    ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def convert_from_db_format(input_time):
    return datetime.strptime(
        input_time,
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    ).strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The `setter` `convert_to_db_format()` works fine, but when I add the `getter` `convert_from_db_format()` it seems to reverse the effect of the setter before inserting to the DB.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include your conversion functions please?

Comment: Also (out of interest), is there a reason why you are using a string column instead of a datetime column?

Comment: Try [Custom Types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html)

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I am using SQLite which doesn't have a specific datetime column https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Youcan still use a datetime column, SQLA will handle it properly.  I get a couple of errors running the code, but I don't see that data format being reversed.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks, using a DateTime in SQLAlchemy is a MUCH better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by @snakecharmerb, a simple solution is to utilise the in-built `datetime` type (instead of writing custom getters/setters).

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped
from datetime import datetime

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class MyTable(Base):
    __table__ = "test_table"

    start_time: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime())
```